# Compare fixed-length hex strings with leading zeroes

Tags: .net

I have two strings:

```
var Number1 = "1CDDE";
var Number2 = "01CDDE";
```

The length of the numbers are fixed, six characters.

I have to compare these numbers without leading zeroes. Should I remove the first zero or add zeroes if a length of a numbers is less than six?

No problem, if the value is int, but when I try to make something like this with strings (parse to int, for example or pass in String.Format), I can't do it.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`string.TrimStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart) to remove the leading zeroes if you have no control over them, or standardize on an approach (either always or never include leading zeroes) if you do.

For example:

```
var equal = "1CDDE" == "01CDDE".TrimStart(new[] { '0' }); // true
```